# MySQL Socket refuses connection after thousands of successive connections

Tags: mysql, sockets, ubuntu, connection, database-connection

I am currently trying to populate a MySQL5.1 database on a current Ubuntu machine with >5,000,000 entries. 
Due to the program's architecture, for each INSERT statement a new database connection is opened and closed. I am aware that this is an expensive operation to do, but changing this would require to change a loooot of code, so I'd rather avoid that.

**The problem** I am facing is that after a while (usually about 12 seconds, but this number increases after some retries) *this process* is not able to connect to the database any more. Other processes can connect to the database without any problem.

I do not think that this is an MySQL issue, cause none of the MySQL logs report any errors. Also, there is max 1 connection open at a time (which I checked by taking a look at the MySQL status variables).

**Question**: Is there a limit of how many successive connections to the socket can be opened in a given time frame?

Here is a simplified perl-script (the actual program is in Java) that leads to the same problem (the database-variables are not included):

```
# ...
my $i = 0;
my $DBH = 0;
for ($i = 0;$i < $MAX; ++$i) {
  $DBH = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$DBNAME:$DBHOST:$DBPORT", $DBUSER, $DBPW)
    or die ("Error - Connection to database failed: \n   $i times ok\n".DBI->errstr);

  $DBH -> disconnect;
  if ($i % 10000 == 0) {
    print $i. " ";
  }
}
```

**Question**: Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try raising the number of allowed connections in /etc/mysql/my.cnf?

```
max_connections        = 300
```

if php, change all instances of mysql_connect() to mysql_pconnect() ?

Comment: there is max 1 connection open at a time, so that's not the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be opening and closing TCP sockets very quickly, you may be accumulating sockets in `TIME_WAIT` state (see [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html)) and on Linux this could cause a process to run out of file descriptors (whereas on Windows this would likely manifest in all processes on the same box failing to connect rather than just a single process as there are no per process socket limits).

Run `netstat` on both the client machine that's running the insertion code and the server that houses the db.

If you are accumulating sockets in `TIME_WAIT` then what you need to do depends on where they are (client or server).

Comment: "but this would likely manifest in all processes on the same box failing to connect rather than just a single process." I disagree. The process is likely running out of file descriptors, which are allocated on a per-process basis.

Comment: Good suggestion! However, I decided to adapt the code to use a persistent connection. Although it was a lot of work, it was worth the trouble cause it works now!

Comment: I'm sure that's a better solution.